# How to create UIImage from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uiimageview, uiimage

In the ipad app im planning to do, it will be all about loading web pages in UIWebView.
I have a feature wherein I will display previews of the UIWebViews, more like thumbnails of these web pages. How do I do this? generating UIImage from these web pages would be cool...
Hope someone can help me achieve this.

Answer (score 6):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourWebView.bounds.size);
        [yourWebView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *resultImageView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

this `resultImageView` will be your answer...