# Thumbnail from NSURL

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am loading files that are downloaded from the web in a UIWebView (HTML files).

Is there a way to create a UIImage from an HTML file located in the Documents folder?

The goal is to auto generate thumbnails without needing to manual create them...

**Update**
My train of thought would be to do something in the line of:

```
NSString * s =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:
                                  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Which of course does not work in this case!

Thanks!

S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469093/how-to-create-uiimage-from-uiwebview)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourWebView.bounds.size);
[yourWebView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *resultImageView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

`resultImageView` will be an image that contains the render of `yourWebView`.

If you want to shrink it down to a thumbnail size from there, I like [Trevor's UIImage category](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) for that purpose.

Comment: I was actually looking to bulk create the thumbnails before presenting the HTML files...

Comment: The thing you've got that renders HTML into a layout is a UIWebView. Whether you present that view on the screen first is another matter entirely--you could do this whole thing in an offscreen CGRect if you want to. But I don't know of a way to do this that *doesn't* use a UIWebView to do the layout.