# Only show section of uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView and i only want to display a certain part of that webview to the user. If there a way of setting the content of the web view.

For example in the picture below the RED is my web view and i only want to show the BLUE content.

[image: web view image]

I know i can offset and use content size, the the content size always starts at point 0,0. Is there a way to start say at (0, 100).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a little tricky, since I assume you're asking for the scroll view to *only* include that portion of the web view, correct? If you just want to *start* at that place, then look at `webview.scrollview.contentOffset`.

To do what you're talking about, you'd have to take a [picture of the webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469093/how-to-create-uiimage-from-uiwebview), and display that. Of course this would invalidate any links, javascript, or other interactive features.

If you needed those things back, you could handle touch events and forward them to the real webview, as long as the page isn't too dynamic.

Personally, I'd probably modify the HTML itself to display the content you want to display rather than trying to snip out a portion of it.

**EDIT**: As I think about it, setting `webView.scrollView.contentOffset` actually might give you exactly what you want, if you also disable scrolling using `webView.scrollview.scrollEnabled = NO`.

Comment: Hi, It doesnt look like there is an easy solution. I have though about extracting the HTML body tag, but it is quite messy. I also thought you could put the webview inside a scroll view and do it that way, but i read that apple doesnt like this.

Comment: Try the above edit. Webviews have their own integrated scrollviews. Nesting scrollviews can sometimes create serious problems with touch handling.